# Markov Property, running maximum of Brownian Motion.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-process

Let $B = (B_t)_{t \geqslant 0}$ be standard Brownian motion. Set $$X_t = \max_{0 \leqslant s \leqslant t} B_s, \ \text{for} \ t \geqslant 0.$$

Is $X= (X_t)_{t\geqslant 0} $ a Markov Process with respect to its natural filtration?

Comment: The analogous question for a random walk has a negative answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683123/the-maximum-of-a-simple-random-walk. So I guess the answer is no, and you can try the same kind of argument. Perhaps $X_t - B_t$ is a Markov process?

Comment: To anonymous downvoter: I see no reason to cast a downvote on this question. Please remember that above all we should be trying to create a welcoming community, and that rejection hurts and is discouraging.

Comment: Thanks @AreaMan. 

And I agree, the downvote is a little harsh; the question may be elementary but it still deserves an answer :) .

Comment: +1 There are plenty of high school and calc I questions here so being "elementary" is not (or shouldn't be) a problem for this question. I suppose though that adding your own thoughts (in a section after your nicely succinct question maybe) might be nice; people here tend to like extra context and at least the appearance of effort from the questioner. Just a little advice :) Might be why you got the -1.

Comment: Indeed, writing your own thoughts generally improves reception. Also, taking the time to carefully work through your feelings about the question in writing, or search the site for similar questions, will usually benefit you -- you may figure out the solution, refine the specific point that you want to ask about, or learn some related information that will help you to understand an eventual answer.