# Is $M_t = \max_{0 \le s \le t}(B_s)$ an Itô Process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I had a conversation today as to whether or not $$M_t = \max_{0 \le s \le t}(B_s)$$ is an Itô process? My intuition is that it is not an Itô process since it needs to remember an arbitrarily ancient event from the past, like the max value, so it doesn't have the Markov property, but it may not be as simple as that.

The idea is that if it is an Itô process then it can be written as some SDE in general form.

Comment: As you said, this process is not markovian so it cannot be Ito process.

Comment: @NN2 what do you think about this answer below? I am just reviewing the reference. Looks like a pretty strong argument at first glance.

Comment: @NN2 I think you are confusing an Ito process with an Ito diffusion.  There is not typically a requirement that an Ito process by Markovian.

Comment: @user6247850 Indeed, the Ito process is not necessary markovian but the Ito diffusion is.

Comment: This doesn't touch on your main question, but your reasoning for why it's not Markov is a bit suspect. 
  Are you okay with the fact $(M_t, B_t)$ is Markov?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I guess not. I guess it is an exercise i could work on along with the other great material posted here.

Answer (score 2):

The running maximum of a Brownian motion $(B_t)$ has the following martingale representation:
$$
M_T=\sqrt{\frac{2T}{\pi}}+\int_0^T 2\bar{\Phi}\!\left(\frac{M_t-B_t}{\sqrt{T-t}}\right)\,dB_t.
$$
(See, e.g., Example 41.13 on page 92 [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=bDQy-zoHWfcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=rogers+williams+diffusions+markov+processes+martingales+II&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFlre1lZ_wAhUF2qQKHZKeDwgQ6AEwAXoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=92&f=false).)

Comment: Is it obvious that this meets the definition of an Ito process?  We would need that there exists a progressively measurable process $H$ such that $M_T = C + \int_0^T H_t dB_t$ for all $T$, but your $H$ also depends on $T$

Comment: Is the integrand not predictable, since $M_{t}$ and $B_{t}$ are adapted and the whole thing is a composition of continuous functions?

Comment: The integrand is predictable, but still depends on $T$.  We need a single progressively measurable process where this holds for all $T$, not a different progressively measurable process for each $T$.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that it may not be that simple.  It doesn't need to "remember" the max value from the past because the max value is given by $M_t$.  If we let $W_t$ be a standard Brownian motion, then $B_t := \int_0^t \text{sgn}(W_s)dW_s$ is as well by Levy's characterization.  From Tanaka's formula, $|W|_t = B_t + L_t$ where $L_t$ is the local time of $W$ at $0$.  The local time is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure and is progressively measurable, so $L_t = \int_0^t K_s ds$ for some progressively measurable process $K$ by the Radon-Nikodym theorem.  Now thanks to a lemma from Skorohod, we know $L_t = \sup_{s \le t}(-B_s)$ (see section 3.5 in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.08912.pdf) paper by Bjork).  If we define $\hat B_t := -B_t$ then $\hat B_t$ is a Brownian motion, and if $M_t := \sup_{s \le t} \hat B_t$ then we have $M_t = L_t$ and is therefore an Ito process.

This shows an example where $M_t$ is defined to be the running max of a specific Brownian motion and is an Ito process.  I'm not certain if that is the case whenever $M_t$ is defined to be the running max of any Brownian motion (here the filtration is larger than the one generated by the Brownian motion we are looking at the running max of), but it certainly shows it is not quite that simple.

Comment: This brings up some great examples. The precise reason I asked this question to discern if 2 Itô processes that produce the same law at any time $T$ could actually be defined differently as standard processes. The example that was brought up, although I haven't confirmed personally, is that $|W_t|$ has the same law as $\max(W_t)$ but if these two may have unique SDEs, which seems to be the case.

Comment: You might have to be careful about what you mean by "law" there.  It's true that for a fixed $t$ we have $|W_t|$ has the same distribution as $M_t := \max_{s \le t}(W_s)$, but the process $(|W_t|)_{t \in [0,T]}$ does not have the same law as the process $(M_t)_{t \in [0,T]}$.  $M$ is increasing, but $|W|$ may increase or decrease.

Comment: I don't agree with your second phrase. The fact that $M_t = |B_t|$ **in law** doesn't mean that knowing $B_t$ is sufficient to determine $M_t$ almost surely. Besides, it seems to me that later, you proved $M_t = \max B_s  = L_t$ **in law**, but this second argument doesn't mean either that $M_t$ is Ito process.
I found this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282527/markov-property-running-maximum-of-brownian-motion , the proof of non markovian property of $M_t$ can be obtained from the first comment of this question.

Comment: OK you've precisely touched on the point, thank you so much. What I am trying to do is empirically measure the distance between the distributions at some time and then the deduce properties about the stochastic differential equation, or Ito process, that produced the distributions. it seems the point here is that I need to look at laws of processes and not just laws of distributions at some time.

Comment: @NN2 I don't understand your first point.  Where did I claim that knowing $B_t$ is sufficient to determine $M_t$?  For your second point, what I proved was that $M_t = \max \hat{B}_s = L_t$ almost surely.  As a consequence, it is true that $\max W_s = L_t$ in law, but that is tangential to this question.  The question you linked to asked about whether $M_t$ is Markov with respect to its natural filtration, which is not the filtration in my proof, so I'm not sure what the relevance is.

Comment: @user6247850 According to the Proposition 3.4, page 13 in your link, the author proved that $\max B_s = L_t$ in law. And in the page 12, it seems to me that the author wrote "...we are not allowed to identify $L_0 (W)$ with $\sup_{s≤t}W^{−}_s$ . We note however that we have ... in distribution". Hence, I think we can only have $L_0(W) = \max B_s$ in law (and not almost surely) as stated in the proposition 3.4.

Comment: @NN2 Right, but if you look at equation (1) on page 12, you will see that we do indeed have $L_t(W) = \max \hat B_s$ almost surely.  In fact, the proof that $L_t(W) = \max W_s$ in distribution relies on the fact that $L_t(W) = \max \tilde{W}_s$ almost surely.